# How to specify a relative path to the local Ivy repo in Gradle?

Tags: ivy, gradle

I'm migrating from Ant/Ivy to Gradle, and am trying to understand how you specify a relative path to the local Ivy repo.  Standalone Ivy sets the variable `${ivy.default.ivy.user.dir}` by default to `.ivy2` in the user home directory, and places the local repo there.

I can simulate this as follows:

```
repositories {
    ivy {
        url "C:/Users/RYAN/.ivy2/local"
        layout 'pattern', {
            artifact "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact](-[classifier])-[revision](.[ext])"
            ivy "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact](-[classifier])-[revision](.[ext])"
    } 
}
```

But I don't want to specify an absolute path.  I see there's a GRADLE_USER_HOME environment variable, but Gradle doesn't set it by default--I have to specify it command line.

Does Gradle provide a way to access a default local Ivy repo?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about using:

```
url "${System.properties['user.home']}/.ivy2/local"
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work.  I'd still like to access/use some of the Ivy _default_ properties, but this will work for avoiding the absolute path.

Comment: I don't think Gradle has such a shortcut ... (i.e. like the mavenCentral() repo one) ... You can always request this feature on the Gradle forums.

Comment: Optionally ... you can always make sure that the ivy.default.ivy.user.dir system property is set .. and use it to replace 'user.home' in my example.